# How to store array of replaysubject in single variable in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I want to store multiple replaysubject in a single array.

My code

```
public filteredSearch: ReplaySubject<any[]> = new ReplaySubject(1);
this.filteredSearch[id].next(filter(somedata));
```

it throws error Cannot read property 'next' of undefined what am i missing here?

Tested on angular 7

Answer (score 0):

`filteredSearch` is not of the type array but of the type ReplaySubject. So `therefor ReplaySubject[id]` is undefinied and undefinied does not have a method called `next`.

I think you wanted this something similar to this:

```
public filteredSearch: Array<ReplaySubject<any>> = new Array<ReplaySubject<any>>();
this.filteredSearch.push(new ReplaySubject<any>(1));
this.filteredSearch[id].next(filter(somedata));
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I had tried declaring Array<ReplaySubject<any>> but i was not pushing in new ReplaySubject<any> in array.now this.filteredSearch[id] = new ReplaySubject<any>(1); helped me.